# ZPL - Print 2 column n rows with dynamic barcode and text

Tags: zebra-printers, zpl

Sticker size: 34mmx48mm. roll with 2 column.

Device: Zebra ZD220

Wanted to print n number of stickers with dynamic barcodes and text.

**Image of barcode designed with Zebra Designer**
[image]

**Exported the script, added the dynamic content to it**
[image]

Here in image, after adding dynamic script content. barcode are getting overlapped.

**Question: How to generate n number of stickers with 2 column sticker size with dynamic content values**

```
CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~
^XA
~TA000
~JSN
^LT0
^MNW
^MTT
^PON
^PMN
^LH0,0
^JMA
^PR4,4
~SD15
^JUS
^LRN
^CI27
^PA0,1,1,0
^XZ
^XA
^MMT
^PW807
^LL304
^LS0
^FO220,65^GFA,885,3020,20,:Z64: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:16F5
^FO636,65^GFA,885,3020,20,:Z64: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:16F5
^FT22,249^BQN,2,6
^FH\^FDLA,9e17028e-c19b-4f5a-8229-dbf00db02862^FS
^FO22,243^GFA,825,1584,44,:Z64: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:B3A1
^FT438,249^BQN,2,6
^FH\^FDLA,9e17028e-c19b-4f5a-8229-dbf00db02862^FS
^FO438,243^GFA,825,1584,44,:Z64:eJzt0zFr20AUB/AnrpwyHFbHM5g4/QYvZPHgVpR+j3JG0GzFIRA62RcMcgeDVg+C0m/QD5DhrlfkxaRrhkAcAnGHDApdNBi779ykcfoBMpS+QeLBj6fH/04A/+sJywAE5k8nDNMAXN21bQBcDUNd+sbOyL35To/yw3aoyYbDwHAV2FmbhbrnbZbZyltXEptEBoJqEdNLmFo0mHHFrsoej0wC0GX10VVONHCSbCEAWH66N1JkRT1VXPGkNRdidknfY3WdEAA22aKRayt4kO88WCVdA5TVQRmiWduwEAbYvR2jtzhFrgRKJ8kO7Bfu7TZEaSHOgV2M2OzO3pzHZI/ee4tkh5fobR5D81shlsAvskHJcm+DxdLbZZ/s3NuRwhqazlkCLV2IOTwroq+t4Mxbls9ph93TwxHKo5jsR0SBxlSvNVIEDgQtLaESTCITztu0M0J81dfmcvzbllYrmAirZbGlJJSCNZALO8LpHldTxPaBNsmnEhtobLUi6xregqoCmiu6m7bXMaZPVqI9zlcZ2YXNsICkus0lj26vH6zap3RfNtd2ILy1P2y2Q1b+FJKHnzetI8skkHUDOgUFRlrdv4Z9yUSrBmpjh5lTbm0RHdu078iieGQNWeCPLFoNxb01f9uaeI5YHzKhKF/TdXBnu43AhJRvPU3STtox7sUERI3G1lM2PtAtbdTc38lJi42VDLQ/t3raOT1MO/p6NwUZlqia0W0V66YxZkk2cpTvKnbAFkvRDO2yH7pFr5mVyAyqKCpLumfa6hOy4fEUylVcANyciIiZo7fMLdpknuif/6fqF5vaQYE=:B3A1
^PQ1,0,1,Y
^XZ
```

Comment: Try simplifying your code by removing the images and stuff that is not needed, or that you are not having a problem with. Also, you have printer configuration "label" that need not be shown here.

Comment: It's not clear what your problem is. Are you printing over already printed labels? How are you transitioning from this script that prints one label to printing several? How are you going to print several labels in the first place if you have the GUIDs hardcoded as an image, like the logo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

above mentioned script exported from zebra designer is completely fine. Script is designed for one row two column. As my ask was to print n no of labels i have iterated the script n times and it worked fine for me.

Answer (score -1):

I think your problem is with the `^PQ` command.

You have:

```
^PQ4,0,1,Y
```

Which mean you are

- Printing 4 rows
- 0 pause between labels
- 1 replication of each serial number
- Override pause count = Yes

If none of that is intentional, and you are having your software generate the data/serial numbers (which I assume, as I don't see `^SF` command) I'd just say `^PQ1` for each label pair you want.